# Fritz!Box 6490 Cable Port Forwarding doesnt actually forward

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, fritzbox

I have this issue for a while now.

I try to do portforwarding.

[image: Port (here for OpenTTD as a test) supposedly forwarded in UDP and TCP]

But... when others want to connect to it (also tested with Minecraft 25565 and Factorio's Port) they dont see me, aka, see me as Offline.

Internet check also confirmed: My 'open' Ports are actually not open.

And the UPNP option doesnt work either as well, not much of a surprise if manual doesnt do it.

Now I looked around a little, trying to see if I can find the issue myself, since I didnt had that issue before, with our former Router (Where it was done the same way and worked!)

Checked IP4/IP6/Mac Address, all correct. Checked Host Name (which was actually set wrong, but didnt help)

Now, I am really no expert with a Fritz!Box, so I am asking here what I can do or check to see what's wrong.

Hope it can be solved

Comment: Seems like noone can help.
Kinda sad, hoped it could be solved.

Answer (score -1):

I have this exact issue bro
It pretty much went from working to not working.
Means either Windows FireWall is on, or it means the FritzBox is broken...

Fritz are very good at breaking... They shouldn't really be sold in my opinion.
Sorry that you got stuck with my curse too bro